# How to show that the intersection of two certain affine varieties is reduced?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, intersection-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\codim{codim}$Let $X=V(I)$, $Y=V(J)$ be two affine varieties. I'd like to know possibile strategies to understand when their schematic intersection, i.e. $X\cap Y=V(I+J)$, is reduced.
I am aware that reduceness is equivalent to Serre's conditions $R_0$+$S_1$ (at least under Noetherian hypothesis), but I don't really know how to use them efficiently, at least in my specific case.
More precisely, the case I am interested in is the following:

Let $V=\mathbb A^{2n}$ be an even dimensional vector space, let $X$ be an half dimensional vector subspace and let $Y=\bigcup_i Y_i \cup \bigcup_j Z_j$, where each $Y_i$, $Z_j$ is again a half dimensional vector subspace of $V$ (the reason for using different notations for them will become clear).

In general, $X\cap Y$ is not reduced: for example it's easy to see that, if $X=V(y-x)$ is the diagonal and $Y=V(xy)$ is the cross inside $\mathbb A^2$, then $X\cap Y=V(x^2, y-x)$ is not reduced…so one certainly needs to put more assumptions on $X,Y$.

I'd like to know if the following two assumptions are actually enough to ensure reduceness for $X\cap Y$:

(*i*) The $X\cap Y_i$'s are all distinct subspaces, of codimension 1 in $X$.

(*ii*) For each $Z_j$, there exists at least one $Y_i$ such that $X\cap Z_j \subsetneq X\cap Y_i$ (in particular, $\codim_X X\cap Z_j\geq 2$).

My intuition is that such an intersection should be at least generically reduced, namely reduced outside the closed locus $\bigcup_j X\cap Z_j$, and I hope these conditions are enough to ensure that nothing bad happens even inside such a locus, but I don't know how to prove that (basically I don't know how to exclude embedded primes).

P.S. If this turns out to be actually false, anyway I'd be interested to know which sort of other ‘reasonable’ conditions on the $Y_i$'s and $Z_j$'s could ensure reducedness of such an intersection.

Comment: Good question. At a wild guess, you might need to assume some independence, that any $m$ of the $Y$'s intersect with $X$ in codimension $m$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But why would that actually be sufficient? Why having such a condition on the $Y_i$'s would allow me to not care at all about the $Z_j$'s?

Comment: Oh, I don't claim it's sufficient. You might need a similar condition on all subsets of the $Z$'s. Even then, will it be sufficient? I'm not sure. In fact I don't know with certainty that the conditions you listed aren't already sufficient - I just have a hunch that they aren't.

Comment: Sorry, you can ignore my comments (and perhaps I will delete them after a while). I misunderstood your question, and I was intersecting the components of $Y$, instead of taking their union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that if there are no $Z$'s, then this works. Indeed, both $X$ and the $Y_i$ are linear spaces, so the intersection $X\cap Y$ is just a union of pairwise different linear spaces, so it is reduced. I think one could write down this with equations.

However, adding the $Z_i$'s is problematic. I think the following example works:
Let $Y=Z(xz,xt,yz,yt)\subseteq \mathbb A^4$. Then $Y=Y_1\cup Z_1$, where $Y_1=Z(z,t)$ and $Z_1=Z(x,y)$. Further let $X=Z(y-z,t)$. Then $X\cap Y_1=Z(y,z,t)$, a hyperplane in $X$ and $X\cap Z_1=Z(x,y,z,t)$, which is contained, but not equal to $X\cap Y_1$. Finally, $X\cap Y=Z(xy,y^2,y-z,t)$ is not reduced.

Here is also a theoretical reason for this example. (This had been the motivation behind my previous attempts at giving an example. In fact, this is essentially the first example I gave, but it didn't work, because I tried to do it without the Z's). Anyway the point is, that $Y$ is a simple example of a union of linear spaces that is not $S_2$. A hyperplane section of something that's not $S_2$ is not $S_1$, so cannot be reduced. The only trick is to figure out how to choose $X$, so its intersection with $Y$ is actually a hyperplane cut of $Y$.

Finally, a little nit picking: $\mathbb A^n$ is **not** a vectorspace, nor are the $X$, the $Y_i$'s and the $Z_i$. They are affine spaces. If you want to say that they all share a common point, then say that.

Comment: Dear @SándorKovács thanks a lot for your answer (the very last tip included :)), which actually gives a counterexample to what I was (way too optimistically) hoping to be true. Nevertheless, if I correctly understood what you said, I'd say that this is not a counterexample having only $Y$'s components: in fact $Y=Z(z,t)$ certainly intersects $X=Z(x-z,t)$ in a line, but $Z=Z(x,y)$ intersects it just in a point. So, how should I modify the condition you suggested accordingly? Should it become something like $Y_i\cap Z_j \nsubseteq X$ $\forall i,j$?

Comment: Hi @Utf, you're right, the example I gave didn't work, but I think it does now. In fact, this was the example I first came up with (when I still remembered to check condition (i)), but then I tried to simplify it.... As for the condition that might work: yes, I think that has a good chance.

Comment: actually I am confused about your new example...I think now both components of $Y$ intersect $X$ in a single point, which is the same for both. So this would be no more a counterexample to my question, since it does not satisfy the condition $(i)$ that I put (the codimensions are not $1$, and more importantly the two intersections are not distinct). According to my intuition (which may be easily wrong, as you had just proven), it should not be possible to find a counterexample having just $Y$'s components, i.e. components satisfying condition $(i)$.

Comment: @Utf, what do you think of this new example?

Comment: Hi @SándorKovács: I'd say this new example is actually again a counterexample to my optimistic guess (indeed it is pretty similar to the very first counterexample that you gave me). Thanks for realizing me that my conditions were not enough, I am now trying to understand if my setting actually fulfills also the condition that you hinted as possibly sufficient, namely $Y_i \cap Z_j \nsubseteq X$. Could you just explain me a bit more why this condition should be enough to ensure that $X\cap (\bigcup_i Y_i\cup\bigcup_j Z_j)$ is reduced? What kind of argument should I use to prove that?

Comment: My rationale for suggesting that was that the $Y_i$ and $Z_j$ are linear spaces,so are their pairwise intersections. If that is not contained in $X$ (which is also linear), then they intersect transversally, so one does not expect "excess" intersection. In other words, I would expect the intersection to be reduced. Of course,this would only tell you that individually the intersections are reduced,but that same assumption also suggests that the union of these intersections are still reduced. I am not claiming this is a proof,just that this was the heuristic thinking that led to that suggestion